# Incorrect Linked List being returned when inserting element at first position

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am a beginner and was practicing a program on Insertion of a node at the first position when several elements are already present in the linked list . Here is my code snippet

```
class LinkedList{
    int data;
    LinkedList next;

    void insertNodeAtTheEnd(int d, LinkedList head){
        LinkedList temp;
        temp = head;
        while(temp.next != null){
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        LinkedList newNode = new LinkedList();
        newNode.data = d;
        newNode.next = null;
        temp.next = newNode;
    }

    void insertNodeAtGivenPosition(int d , int pos , LinkedList head){
        LinkedList temp;
        temp = head;
        int tempPos = 1;
        LinkedList newNode = new LinkedList();
        LinkedList before = temp;
        if(pos == 1){

            newNode.data = d;
            newNode.next = temp;
            temp = newNode;     
        }
        else { 
            while(temp != null){
                if(pos == tempPos){
                    newNode.data = d;
                    newNode.next = before.next ;
                    before.next = newNode;
                }

                before = temp ;
                temp = temp.next ;
                tempPos++;
            }   
        }   
    }

    void printLinked(LinkedList head){
        LinkedList temp = head;
        while(temp.next != null){
            System.out.print(temp.data + "->");
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        System.out.print(temp.data +"\n");
    }

}

class LinkedListMain{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        LinkedList node1 = new LinkedList();
        node1.data = 10;
        node1.next = null;

        LinkedList head;
        head = node1;

        head.insertNodeAtTheEnd(8, head);
        head.insertNodeAtTheEnd(6, head);
        head.insertNodeAtTheEnd(7, head);
        head.insertNodeAtTheEnd(11, head);
        head.insertNodeAtTheEnd(5, head);
        head.insertNodeAtTheEnd(2, head);
        head.printLinked(head);
        head.insertNodeAtGivenPosition(4 , 3 , head);  //line 1
        head.printLinked(head);
        head.insertNodeAtGivenPosition(1 , 1 , head);  //line2
        head.printLinked(head);             
    }
}
```

For the above code , after inserting element at third position (line 1) using method "insertNodeAtGivenPosition()" , the code works fine and the output is shown below

```
10->8->6->7->11->5->2
10->8->4->6->7->11->5->2
```

But when I try to use the same logic to insert element at first position(line 2) and print the list , the first element is not inserted and the output looks like

```
10->8->6->7->11->5->2
10->8->4->6->7->11->5->2
10->8->4->6->7->11->5->2
```

What am I doing wrong? There seem to be some issue with the value of "head".

Comment: if you're inserting at the beginning , what should `newNode.next` be ? It should be the earlier head !

Answer (score 0):

In order to insert at the beginning, you have to change `head` to reference the new node. However, `head` is passed to your method, which cannot change it.

In order for this to work, you'll need to return the new `head`:

```
LinkedList insertNodeAtGivenPosition(int d , int pos , LinkedList head){
    LinkedList temp;
    temp = head;
    int tempPos = 1;
    LinkedList newNode = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList before = temp;
    if(pos == 1) {
        newNode.data = d;
        newNode.next = head;
        head = newNode;     
    } else { 
        while(temp != null){
            if(pos == tempPos){
                newNode.data = d;
                newNode.next = before.next;
                before.next = newNode;
            }

            before = temp;
            temp = temp.next;
            tempPos++;
        }   
    }   
    return head;
}
```

And the method call should be:

```
head = head.insertNodeAtGivenPosition(1 , 1 , head);
```

Of course, you don't need the `head` argument, since it's an instance method, so you can change it to:

```
LinkedList insertNodeAtGivenPosition(int d , int pos) {
    LinkedList head = this;
    LinkedList temp = head;
    int tempPos = 1;
    LinkedList newNode = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList before = temp;
    if(pos == 1){
        newNode.data = d;
        newNode.next = head;
        head = newNode;     
    } else { 
        while(temp != null) {
            if(pos == tempPos){
                newNode.data = d;
                newNode.next = before.next ;
                before.next = newNode;
            }

            before = temp ;
            temp = temp.next ;
            tempPos++;
        }   
    }   
    return head;
}
```

and call it with:

```
head = head.insertNodeAtGivenPosition(1 , 1);
```